# Docker Django image running but not found on localhost

Tags: django, docker

I am trying to run a Django docker image. The image itself is running in the command line without any errors. However when I go to the URL my image is hosted at, the web page is not found.

Below is my docker file I used to build the image

```
    FROM python:3.6
    MAINTAINER c15523957

    RUN apt-get -y update
    RUN apt-get -y upgrade

    RUN apt-get -y install libgdal-dev

    RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app

    COPY requirements.txt /usr/src/app/
    COPY . /usr/src/app

    WORKDIR /usr/src/app

    RUN pip install --upgrade pip
    RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

    EXPOSE 8000
    CMD ["python", "manage.py", "runserver", "0.0.0.0:8000"]
```

Below is the command used to run the image

```
  docker run -it -p8001:8000 c15523957/backendimage7
```

The console logs the message

```
  System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
  December 11, 2018 - 15:05:03
  Django version 2.1.3, using settings 'backendproject.settings'
  Starting development server at http://0.0.0.0:8000/
  Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
```

However when I go to the browser the web page is not found.

**Note:** When I run the Django application without the Docker image the webpage is seen. This is done with

```
   python manage.py runserver
```

**SOLUTION**

I was using docker toolbox for windows. Instead of local dcker toolbox binds to the address 192.168.99.100 . So by going to port ....

```
    192.168.99.100:8001
```

I was able to access my web page

Comment: What url do you try in browser?

Comment: localhost:8001, but i tried the other just in case , no luck

Comment: In your `docker run` command, do you have space after `-p` flag? in your question it's: `-p8001:8000`

Comment: yes I have the space in the command

Comment: Have no idea what's wrong. Give a try: `http://127.0.0.1:8001`

Comment: No luck, thanks for the help anyways